# Jump to vim buffer by number?

Tags: vim, editor, buffer

I have some "buffer bar" at the top, showing my buffers like tabs in a browser.

In a browser I can ctrl-1, ctrl-2 etc. to jump to tabs.

What can I do in vim to jump to the buffer I want really quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have some "buffer bar" at the top, showing my buffers like tabs in a browser.
>
> What can I do in vim to jump to the buffer I want really quickly?

Since there is no built-in "buffer bar" in Vim you must have installed a third-party plugin which, hopefully, comes with some documentation. Did you read it? Since you didn't tell us what plugin you use we can only answer with built-in commands.

The built-in command for navigating to buffer 6 is `:b6`. If you don't know a buffer's number you can:

- cycle through the buffer list with `:bn[ext]` and `:bp[revious]`,
- do `:ls` (or `:buffers`, or `:files`, the three are synonymous) followed by `:b6`,
- do `:b foo<Tab>`.

The last method being the most efficient and scalable.

> Oh I just checked with `:buffers`, and the buffers I have open have the numbers `5`, `6`, `9`, etc. all random. How do I choose from these?

No, buffer numbers are not "random" at all. When a buffer is added to the buffer list it is assigned a fixed number that's equal to the number of the last buffer in the list plus 1. The holes in your list are either due to:

- some buffers being hidden, you can see them with `:ls!`,
- or some buffers being wiped out from the list.

Comment: I just checked with `:ls!` and there are actually all the numbers sequentially, but lots have `u` after; what does that mean?

Comment: It means "unlisted".

Answer (score 1):

`:b x`, where x is the number of the buffer that you want to edit.

EDIT: If you want to mimic the tab behaviour you could also use tabs, which are also supported in vim, it also supports `ctrl + page up/down`. See `help tabs` for documentation.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for me. It's showing buffers I don't even have open

Comment: Oh I just checked with `:buffers`, and the buffers I have open have the numbers `5, 6, 9, ` etc. all random. How do I choose from these?

Comment: Well `:b 5` for buffer number 5, `:b 6` for buffer number 6 and so on. Or did I misinterstand your question?

Answer (score 0):

For those wondering, I'm sharing here a way to switch to a buffer dynamically where the buffer number is stored in a variable:

```
:let var = 2
:execute 'b' . var
```

This would switch to buffer 2.